# Building android go from AOSP Q Beta 1 code

Tags: android, android-source, rom, custom-rom, android-go

I am newbie to ROM development. I have a Moto e 1st gen device sitting around. I wanted to give it another life. So I was trying to build Android Go from AOSP Q Beta 1 source code. I don't know how to add a product and how to configure it to build Android Go. Please help me to configure and build it.

Answer (score 6):

To build a rom from scratch, you need the device trees, kernel source code(or pre-built image), vendor blobs and the required HALs. From your question I understand you don't have any device tree lying around for your device. First try to build roms like LineageOS using the existing trees for your device. Also the Q source code is not the real deal. It is only the master branch and the full source code will only be released once Q is announced.So as I said, try building roms like LineageOS first.

Comment: I have created device tree for my device and able to build and flash. But, it is regular(full) version of android. I wanted to build "android go" version of it. How to do that?

Comment: @VivekRajendran To build the go version, you can call the generic go properties makefile in your device tree. If your device have 512MB of ram you need to call the build/target/product/go_defaults_512.mk makefile in your device tree, or call build/target/product/go_defaults.mk makefile. Keep in mind that Android Pie and probably Android Q have issues on Go editions.

Comment: Will try and let you know