# How can I get Android-Go source code instead of AOSP

Tags: android, android-go

I'd like to make Android Go instead of using AOSP.
But have no information except this site (https://www.android.com/versions/go-edition/)

Please let me know any hint or contact points if any.

1. Can I compile Android Go from my AOSP code?
2. Do I need to contact google person to get some right to handle Android GO source code?

Thanks

Comment: probably this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646338/building-android-go-from-aosp-q-beta-1-code
read out the comments!

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know Android Go Edition is a Trimmed down lighten version of AOSP to run on Low-end chips with more optimization in code than AOSP which are tends to run on High-end SoC's but that is done all on Manufacturers side Google don't provide this.
But you can contact Google to know more about it and If you are planning to Launch a device.